# i have used image as navbar brand in my header but the image comes out of the header how can i solve this in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

here my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bgc" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="img/log1.jpg" class="img-responsive"/></a>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
         <li ><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

The o/p is
[image]

but i want my brand image to be fit inside the header ..how can i solve this issue?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply some width on .navbar-brand class.
e.g.

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;

    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: no it is not working..look at my out put http://prntscr.com/7ft21d  . width is not a problem ..height only gives problem please help me out

Comment: see the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KKXETL1iqUqQHI96K94U?p=preview with the width applied

Comment: and this one without the width http://plnkr.co/edit/OToYbqq40l1cYPaHBOrf?p=preview